Css свойство hover на тачскринах
Предположим на элементе по средством css через событие :hover
Присвоено свойство, любое. Допустим изменение высоты элемента....
Давно заметил, что на пк данное событие работает хорошо. А вот на тачскринах на половину.
Когда на тачскрине нажимаем на элемент и удерживаем, допустим передвигаем блок. После того как передвинули, отпускаем. Высота элемента, присвоенная через hover не возвращается в исходное. Только если кликнуть по экрану, на пустое место и тд. Только тогда высота станет прежней...
Собственно вопрос, ранее решал это через js, путем добавления и удаления класса. Что та подсказывает, что данную задачу возможно разрешить через css. Как?

:active?

Тоже самое, работает криво. К тому же кликать необходимо

hover это состояние при наведении которого в тачскринах быть не может но это состояние всё равно работает но при click

С помощью css никак вроде, только в jQuery знаю есть keypress, keyup и прочие слушатели.
